# Почему не меняются адреса переменных функции при смене порядка их проявления в коде?

Tags: c, стек, адрес

Адреса переменных int auth_flag и char password_buffer[], которые попадают в стек, не меняются, когда я меняю порядок их проявления в функции

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password)
{
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "brilling") == 0)
    {
        auth_flag = 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
    {
        auth_flag = 1;
    }

    return auth_flag;
}
```

Comment: Это никаким стандартом не оговаривается, в каком порядке и как компилятор размещает переменные...

Comment: Исходный посыл, что адреса переменных как-то зависят от порядка их объявления в функции, не верен. Да и проверки адресов в коде нет, так что непонятно, с чего вы решили, что там что-то меняется или нет. Посыл, что они обязательно попадают в стек, тоже неверный.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ответ! Просто я думал, что они попадают в стек по принципу FILO

Comment: переменная `int auth_flag = 0;` не будет храниться в стеке и не будет иметь адрес при оптимизации. место хранения по умолчании автоматическое `auto int auth_flag = 0;` Вы пример  привели неправильно, и не видно что у вас адрес не меняется.

Comment: Спасибо большое